# Symfony2 wrong locale detection?

Tags: symfony, localization, translation

Following Symfony2 guide about [translation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/translation.html) i found that inferred locale from http headers (stored in `$this->get('session')->getLocale()`) is wrong (sent **it**, inferred **en**):

> Host  localhost User-Agent    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1
>   Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Language   it-it,it;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Is this a normal behaviour? Or should i set something in order to get localization working out of the box?

Comment: I found a method named `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::getPreferredLanguage()` that should be called if this is working, but I couldn't find any call to this function in the code. I think you should file a bug report.

Comment: @greg0ire i can't report the bug if i'm not sure this is the wrong behavior...

Comment: you can never be 100% sure and since this is not documented, reporting a bug does not seem that bad. Plus, you will certainly get an answer (and a good one) to your problem. Don't be shy! +1 for your question

Comment: It's the correct behavior. The default locale is the one specified in your config.yml, not the one sent by browser.

Answer (score 7):

I looked more thoroughly onto the code today, because I was experiencing the same problem as you, and it appears that the language comes from `Session::getLocale()`. But Symfony2 never calls `Session::setLocale()`, and sets the `locale` member of the `Session` object. A google search for "symfony2 session setlocale" leads to [this § of the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_controller.html#persisting-data-in-the-session)

So I ended up putting this line on top of the controller I was working on, and it worked :

```
$this->getRequest()->getSession()->setLocale(
    $this->getRequest()->getPreferredLanguage());
```

Now I guess this is not acceptable, because you're not going to add this on top of each and every controller. Plus, this should not be done for every request, it should only be done for the first one, when the user has no session yet. If anyone knows how to do this feel free to edit this answer.

Answer (score 4):

per HTTP-Standard you should be using a different URL for each translated version of the page.  What remains is a simple action that will infer the best-to-use locale from the request and redirect to the corresponding page:

```
/**
 * @Route("/")
 */
public function localeRedirectAction() {
    /* @var $request \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request */
    /* @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session */
    $req = $this->getRequest();
    $session = $this->get('session');

    $session->setLocale($req->getPreferredLanguage(array('de', 'en')));

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
}
```

if you need to do this for any page, you'll basically need to do the same, but within a Listener for the `kernel.request`-Event. In order to be reliably called after the route-matcher did it's work you should set the `priority` of the listener to a value < 0:

```
# services.yml
services:
  my_locale_listener:
    class: Namespace\LocaleListener
    tags: [{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: -255 }]
    arguments: [ @service_container, [ 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'es', 'it' ] ]
```

the listener would then look like this:

```
class LocaleListener {
    public function __construct($container, $availableLocales) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->availableLocales = $availableLocales;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $e) {
        $req = $e->getRequest();
        $locale = $req->getPreferredLanguage($this->availableLocales);

        // generate a new URL from the current route-name and -params, overwriting
        // the current locale
        $routeName = $req->attributes->get('_route');
        $routeParams = array_merge($req->attributes->all(), array('_locale' => $locale));
        $localizedUrl = $this->container->get('router')->generateUrl($routeName, $routeParams);

        $e->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($localizedUrl));
    }
}
```

P.S. i'm not entirely confident that this code actually works, but it should give a basic idea on how this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can register listener like follow:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class LocaleListener
{
    private $container;
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, $defaultLocale = 'nl')
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->container->has('session')) {
            return;
        }

        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->setLocale($this->defaultLocale);
    }
}
```

([gist](https://gist.github.com/1467691))

Just after framework session setup stage:

```
<service id="my.event_listener.locale_listener" class="MyBundle\MyEventListener\LocaleListener">
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.request" method="onKernelRequest" priority="100" />
    <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
</service>
```

([gist](https://gist.github.com/1467713))

Comment: You could actually modify it to get the Request object and use getPreferredLocale method, but I like the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a LocaleListener which is not redirecting you to a locale-specific url, it does however set the locale settings for you ;)

Code in the services.yml

```
services:
    acme.demobundle.listener.request:
        class: Namespace\LocaleListener
        tags: [{ name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest, priority: -255 }]
        arguments: [ @service_container, [ 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'it', 'es' ] ]
```

and the actual listener:

```
class LocaleListener
{
    protected $container;
    protected $availableLocales;

    public function __construct(\Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container $container, $availableLocales) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->availableLocales = $availableLocales;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $e) {
        $req = $e->getRequest();
        $locale = $req->getPreferredLanguage($this->availableLocales);
        $session = $this->container->get('session');
        $session->setLocale($locale);
    }
}
```