# How to translate language in Symfony 2, according to accept language header?

Tags: php, symfony

I have

config.yml

```
#Here locale is en
translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
...
session:
    default_locale: %locale%
```

routing.yml

```
AcmeDemoBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /{_locale}/index
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Default:index, _locale: de}
    requirements:
    _locale: en|de
```

So here by manually typing URL will lead   `/en/index` to  English and `/de/index` to German.

How we can make automatically go to german, if browser Accept language is de_DE or de(German), else go to english(all other browser Accept languages)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically you can do something like that

```
$this->get('session')->setLocale(
    $request->getPreferredLanguage(array('en', 'de'))
);
```

and its should do the trick. But yeah add it in every action can be hard... that why you can create own kernel event listener.

Those links can be helpful I think:

[Symfony2 wrong locale detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656114/symfony2-wrong-locale-detection)

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html

Comment: Where should I create kernel event listener and how? I am not familar with it.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](http://packagist.org/packages/jms/i18n-routing-bundle), which automatically handles the locale in URLs. On the default URL, it will optionally use the preferred locale.

The Kernel event listener is a good option for which you can find information [in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html). However, keep in mind that you should only trigger it on new sessions to make sure the users can still manually select the language they view the site in.

Comment: @louis-philippe-huberdeau Do you know how trigger the listener only on new sessions? Regards!