# change locale symfony 2.3

Tags: php, symfony, locale

I just began with symfony
I'm trying to build a multilang website but I have a problem to change the locale

I read some posts and I read the documentation about this but the locale don't change, I try:

```
public function indexAction()
{    
    $this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'fr');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $locale = $request->getLocale();
    return $this->render('PhoneMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('locale'=>$locale));
}
```

but the value in $locale is always 'en' (my default locale)

I also try

```
public function indexAction()
{    
    $this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'fr');

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $request->setLocale('fr');
    $locale = $request->getLocale();

    return $this->render('PhoneMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig',array('locale'=>$locale));
}
```

In this case $locale is fr but the translations are always from messages.en.yml

I'd like in a first time to detect the user locale using $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], maybe using a listner on each page actualisation ?

and after I will create a route to change the locale

But I 'd like to find a way to change the locale.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350846/symfony2-locale-detection-not-considering-locale-in-session/16356280#16356280) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412476/how-to-translate-language-in-symfony-2-according-to-accept-language-header) answers.

**LanguageListener.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class LanguageListener
{
    private $session;

    public function setSession(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function setLocale(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage(array('en', 'de')));

    }
}
```

**services.yml:**

```
acme.language.kernel_request_listener:
    class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LanguageListener
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocale }
```

About wrong locale detection in twig, there could be a lot of different causes. Search through the SO, you'll definitely find the answer. Make sure that your '_local' var is defined right, make sure that you put your languages files in the right place, etc. FInally, read again the last version of the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

Comment: What is the function `setSession` here ?

Answer (score 0):

I however added this to make it more dynamic

**services.yml**

```
 services:
        acme.language.kernel_request_listener:
            class: Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LanguageListener
            tags:
                - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: setLocale }
            arguments: [ @router, @service_container ]
```

**LanguageListener.php:**

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;

class LanguageListener
{
     private $session;
     private $container;
     private $router;

    public function __construct($router, $container)
    {
        // ...
        $this->router= $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function setSession(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function setLocale(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();    
        $request->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage($this->container->parameters['jms_i18n_routing.locales']));

    }
}
```

Just to be able to get the parameters and values from config.yml.

Regards,
Wick

Answer (score 0):

If for example your default locale is french, except for one controller you want to have the default locale set to english can do that:

routing.yml

```
desktop_comingsoonpage:
    resource: "@RemmelComparabusBundle/Controller/ComingsoonpageController.php"
    defaults: { _locale: en }
    type:     annotation
```

more info : [Symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#the-locale-and-the-url)