# Symfony2 TranslatorListener local culture issue

Tags: php, symfony, events, event-handling, symfony1

I am using redirection from symfony 1 to symfony 2.6.9 with authenticated user. The db is the same. I am using sf1 action to set the web page culture. In sf2 controller I can get the correct culture via

```
$culture = $this->getRequest()->getLocale()
```

but the translator instance uses the default variable.

here are the **kernel.request** event listeners from `app/console debug:event-dispatche kernel.request`:

| #1 | Nelmio\CorsBundle\EventListener\CorsListener::onKernelRequest()

| #2 | Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure()

| #3    | Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest()

| #4    | Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest()

| #5    | Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest()

| #6    | Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest()

| #7    | FOS\RestBundle\EventListener\BodyListener::onKernelRequest()

| #8    | Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\TranslatorListener::onKernelRequest()

| #9    | Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest()

| #10   | Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest()

| #11   | Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest()

**Please any idea.**

Comment: Check if this helps you:

[LocaleListener][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484027/translations-in-symfony-2-3-locale-in-request