# Defining locale in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, locale

I have a Symfony application which is in french.

I want to define the locale in the whole application so I use in my controller:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, $this->get('request')->getLocale());
```

With this I have days of week and months in french.

Which is the best way to achieve that in avoiding repeat in all controller's actions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to this?

In your `config.yml`

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: fr_FR }
    default_locale:  fr_FR
```

Comment: Yes but actually it doesn't define the fr_FR, with this I have 'fr_FR' in the result of the function $this->get('request')->getLocale(), but I have to use setlocale after. I'm looking for define locale once and for all.

Comment: This answer can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243426/change-locale-symfony-2-3?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Think event listeners are the way to go here, did a quick Google and ended up here which should get you in the right direction.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html