# How to configure Symfony2 sticky locale during session

Tags: php, symfony, locale, multilingual

I would like to translate my website thanks to an link on the right top.

I found out that, since Symfony 2.1, the locale is not stored in the session anymore.

So, I followed this Symfony documentation: [Making the Locale "Sticky" during a User's Session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/session/locale_sticky_session.html)

**...Bundle/Service/LocaleListener.php**

```
class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale)
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
              return;
        }

        $locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale');
        var_dump($locale);

        if ($locale) {
             $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    static public function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

**...Bundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
locale_listener:
    class: ..Bundle\Service\LocaleListener
    arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

**./app/config/config.yml**

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: en }
```

And, I add two links to translate my website on the parent twig template, shown below ([Symfony2 locale languages whole page event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903963/symfony2-locale-languages-whole-page-event-listener)).

**base.html.twig**

```
<li><a href="{{-
                path(app.request.get('_route'),
                app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale' : 'fr'}))
            -}}">FR</a></li>
<li><a href="{{-
                path(app.request.get('_route'),
                app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale' : 'en'}))
            -}}">EN</a></li>
```

### Problem and Question

When I click on one of these links, the parameter `_locale` is added.

For instance:

```
satisfaction?_locale=fr
```

So, the value of the `_locale` parameter is `fr`. Consequently, my website should be translated in french.

Nevertheless, that

```
var_dump($locale)
```

in the listener is displayed three times:

1. > null
2. > en
3. > null
   >   I don't understand why the `_locale` parameter is not found when it display `null` and why the `en`?

Comment: `_locale` should be part of the url hierarchy like in `example.com/{_locale}/satisfaction ` not as a GET parameter (`example.com/satisfaction?_locale=fr`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your listener, you will catch all request and subrequest that is not needed. This explain the three times apparition.

Try to add this following code to your `onKernelRequest` method:

```
if (HttpKernel::MASTER_REQUEST != $event->getRequestType()) {
    return;
}
```

This will avoid subRequests and possibly resolve your problem.

Comment: Ok, I added it on the top of my onKernelRequest method. Now, I've only two 'null' displayed.. But it not resolve my problem.

Comment: In my listener, I use `$request->get('_locale')` instead of `$request->attributes->get('_locale')`, could you try it ?

Comment: OK. Now, it displays "en" in every instance, dispite the url is `satisfaction?_locale=fr`... (by the way, thanks for your help)

Comment: As indicated in the comment, your locale listener must be registered before the default Locale listener.

In my Symfony 2.3 project, the default locale listner has a priority of 16. Try to change the priority of your listener, to 10 for exemple, or less...

Comment: OK, I tried 10 & 1, it display "fr" in every instance. I do not understand why the listener don't retrieve the value of _locale parameter!

Comment: 'fr' is the value you expected, no ?

It's because the default locale listener do stuff before yours.

Comment: I expect that the website is in French when I click on the link `FR` and in English when I click on `EN`. (Look at the twig template).

Comment: Didn't understand, changing priority solved your problem or not ?

Comment: Which Symfony version do you have ?

Comment: Here my locale listener, if you want to check: http://pastebin.com/wqhYjmsC

I added database locale storage feature on it, you can ignore this.

Comment: Thank you a lot. I did not read correctly your first comment and I wrote `$request->getLocale()` instead of `$request->get('_locale');`. It works now. Thank you ;)