# Symfony translations use always default EN

Tags: php, symfony, localization, twig, translation

I have italian language set on my browser, but symfony localization give me only english translations.
How can I get italian strings if i access the page with italian browser?

Now i see "pluto" in EN Browser and in IT Browser.

Config.yml:

```
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
```

messages.en.yml:

```
Pippo: pluto
```

messages.it.yml:

```
Pippo: paperino
```

index.html.twig:

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                {% trans %}
                    Pippo
                {% endtrans %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to set current locale from headers you need to a make an event listener for `kernel.request` event that sets `$request->setLocale(...)`.

See similar questions:

- [Symfony2 locale languages whole page event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903963/symfony2-locale-languages-whole-page-event-listener)
- [Symfony2 wrong locale detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656114/symfony2-wrong-locale-detection)
- http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/locale_sticky_session.html